# Setting up a solver loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, solver

How do I set up a loop that solves a column of objective cells vs a column of variable cells?

It doesn't matter that type of solver it is, "GRG Nonlinear" seems to work fine.

My objective cells are E7:E207
Where the solution is minimized or =0 because I want a real root.

My variable cells are D7:D207

The variables that it is solving are a cubic equation where it outputs the real root (no imaginary parts). I've looked around the forum but I can't really seem to make much sense.

My basic macro so far:

```
Sub Solver()
'
' Solver Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
    Range("E8").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$E$7", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$7", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$E$7", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$7", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro? I haven't used solver myself, as of yet. Thus I would probably re-invent the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered many times.

The following will solve your problem ...

```
Sub mySolve()
Dim SetAddr As String, ChgAddr As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 7 To 207
    SetAddr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Address
    ChgAddr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Address
    SolverOk SetCell:=SetAddr, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=ChgAddr, Engine:=1
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
Next i

End Sub
```